# Select data where datetime is less than 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql, freeradius

I have a freeradius-mysql query to select data where **acctstarttime is MORE THAN 30 days**:

below is the query:

```
SELECT SUM(acctinputoctets -
           GREATEST((30 - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acctstarttime)), 0)) +
       SUM(acctoutputoctets -
           GREATEST((30 - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acctstarttime)), 0))
  FROM radacct
 WHERE username = 'user2'
   AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acctstarttime) + acctsessiontime > 30
```

I would like to have a query of the same nature that selects data where **acctstarttime is LESS THAN 30 days** and im having a hard time.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which kind of database are you using?  I'm guessing MySQL, but can you confirm please?

Comment: if possible add table with sample data

Comment: yes I am using mysql.
the accctstarttime value is same as "2016-04-24 06:20:45"

Comment: this is a sample value: [http://prntscr.com/awic0a](http://prntscr.com/awic0a)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  acctstarttime 
FROM    radacct   
WHERE   acctstarttime < ADDDATE(acctstarttime, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

> For more info and functions: [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)